# How to monitor outgoing MIDI messages in CoreMIDI?

Tags: ios, objective-c, macos, midi, coremidi

Is there a way to take a device's destination endpoint and monitor what messages are being sent to it via CoreMIDI?

Comment: Monitoring the messages sent to it by your app, or by other apps? (Doing the latter required a custom MIDI driver on OS X. I don't know if it's possible on iOS, but it seems unlikely.)

Answer (score 0):

[This here is a very good free MIDI Monitor](http://www.snoize.com/MIDIMonitor/)

I have also built a MIDI Monitor with Xcode for iMac and iPhone using coreMIDI. The only problem I have is the "MIDIThruConnectionCreate" for MIDI Thru. Of corse I could send the received MIDI data packet to MIDI out, but this is not the right way.

Answer (score 0):

MIDIThruConnection is for this. See MIDIThruConnection.h in CoreMIDI.framework for more details.